# How to autogenerate a date in a libre calc

Tags: libreoffice-calc, date

I think this is easy but I am not finding solutions online. I have recurring bills and would simply like date values to change every month in their respective cells.

For example if cell A2 due date shows 12/24/2019 and it's now 12/25/2019, then I would like the cell A2 due date to now become 1/24/2020.

Then when it's 1/25/2020 the next date is 2/25/2020 etc.

Likewise, if it's an annual bill, and cell A2 due date is 12/24/2019  and it's now 12/25/2019 then cell A2 due date changes to 12/24/2020.

Is there a simple function for this?

Comment: It seems to me that you haven't described 'the full problem' with the text here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have e.g. 2019-12-03 in A1 (that is 'yesterday' as I write this)
then a cell containing the formula below will show the date one month later.
Edit A1 to contain a date AFTER or EQUAL to the current date and the formula will show an empty cell.

`=IF(TODAY()>A1;DATE(YEAR(A1);MONTH(A1)+1;DAY(A1));"")`

For "an annual bill" the `+1` would need to be just after YEAR() instead.

---

This formula (a):
`=DATE(YEAR(TODAY());MONTH(TODAY());25)`
... will display the 25:th of the current month, until the month changes - e.g. for a monthly updated due date.

Similarly (b):
`=DATE(YEAR(TODAY());1;25)`
will show January 25th the current year (i.e. change as the year changes).

if you replace A1 with $A$100 above, to get this (c):
`=IF(TODAY()>$A$100;DATE(YEAR($A$100);MONTH($A$100)+1;DAY($A$100));"")`
and place either of a) and b) in A100, you will see each and any cell containing c) update as you either change A100 manually, or the formula there gives a new value (as shown above at a or b).

Or maybe (d) to show EITHER the 25th of current month while current date is before that, OR 25th of NEXT month if current date is past the 25th.
`=IF( DAY(TODAY()) <25;`
`DATE( YEAR(TODAY()); MONTH(TODAY())  ; 25);`
`DATE( YEAR(TODAY()); MONTH(TODAY())+1; 25)`
`)`

---

*Please use an unambiguous date format, not something that is prone to be guessing game depending on the actual date.*

Comment: Will that work every month? Won't it stop after it updates the first time.

Comment: If you update the (input) value in `A1`, the formula will update (recalculate) at the same moment. Just as in any other spreadsheet - there is no magic here, it is very similar to "mechanics" - as in "bike mechanics".

Comment: How about a, b, c, and d formulas... might that be the "tools" you need?

Comment: I eventually figured it out but then I saw those A B and C and they seem better than what I came up with.

Comment: =IF(DAY(TODAY())>24,EDATE(MONTH(TODAY())&"/24/"&YEAR(TODAY()),1),MONTH(TODAY())&"/24/"&YEAR(TODAY()))

Comment: On StackExchange (e.g. Super user); If you find an answer helpful, mark it as "the accepted answer" by activating the tick to the left of it. Other answers can be marked as similarly valuable by increasing the number on the left of them.